# Save PowerPoint (fullscreen) presentation view as document or vector image?

Tags: vector, svg, export, microsoft-powerpoint

I have not found a way to save the presentation view at a time X during a presentation as a document of some kind, ideally as a vector graphic (i.e. as PPTX, PDF, SVG or similar).

Is this true, or is there any way -- other than the trivial screenshot?

An alternative would be to save the presentation view as a high-resolution bitmap, i.e. with a much higher resolution than the presentation screen.

Comment: @Hamid's made some good points. To expand a little: you can't export the current state of the slide show if there are animations on the slide, but you can do File | Save as and choose EMF if you want a vector graphic of the slide *as it appears in Normal view*.  Or use VBA's .Slide.Export method to export the slide to a high resolution PNG image.  If you need to export a slide at a certain state during an animation, have a look at Massimo Rondini's PPSplit add-in https://www.maxonthenet.altervista.org/ppsplit.php

Comment: Steve! This sounds totally awesome and like an absolute killer application that really should be a part of PowerPoint in the first place! I can't wait to try PpSplit (but will take a little time as I'm "unfortunately" on my way to a few days off :)

Comment: PowerPoint isn't really graphic design software, but I'm pretty sure you can export a document as PDF. Try that. If you have other questions, it's probably better to post PowerPoint questions on SuperUser.

Comment: Note this is not about saving PPTX as PDF, which is a no-brainer (Save As -> PDF). Also, to some people including me, PowerPoint IS a totally awesome vector graphics editor ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

You can save a slide as EMF which is Microsoft's own vector format. The saved file doesn't contain anything which is the result of a running effect. For ex. if something in the image grows or turns during the presentation, you cannot get a certain snapshot as a vector because it doesn't exist. The movement is calculated only as sequence of bitmap images in rendering.

If you need a certain evolved state as a vector you must manually edit a new static slide which contains the evolved versions of the shapes. Save it as EMF. It can be imported to vector graphics programs and used as any vector content. Save there the image as SVG. That's the native format in Inkscape.

Comment: "you cannot get a certain snapshot as a vector because it doesn't exist". That makes sense. I hope however that PpSplit as mentioned by Steve will be able to save vectorial PDFs from "evolved" steps, i.e. after each animation. OTOH, should it save "only" high-resolution bitmaps, that would be also very useful.

Comment: PS: the example PDF files on the PPspliT Homepage seem to be vector files, so that looks very promising.

Comment: PPspliT doesn't save vector or bitmap files; it converts your presentation into a new one with a new slide for each step of any applied animations.  Once it does that, you can use PPT's own Save As | Files of Type:  EMF to save the slide to a vector graphic.

Comment: PPspliT works extremely well, so this fully solves the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

A late response.

> An alternative would be to save the presentation view as a high-resolution bitmap

It can be exported as Video. If by "high-resolution bitmap", 4K is enough 3840x2160, export the video as 4K and then extract a frame using, for example, VLC Player. You can do that even if your working monitor is only FullHd for example.

Some parameters of the export can be changed using macros. For example, you can change the standard export of 30fps to 60.

Here is a discussion of a macro (not working perfectly) but I want to mention something

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-export-video-from-powerpoint-at-60fps/6f4fd6a9-57d3-4137-b417-551757b9ee55

It indicates the vertical resolution. Probably you can change it to 8K.

---

In the comments, a Git is mentioned. PPspliT wich I have not tested but sounds promising.